# Why doesn't AssocQueryString find executable associated to image extensions?

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-10, file-type, file-association

I'm using **[AssocQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-assocquerystringw)** in order to get the executable associated to certain extensions.

It works good for extensions like `.pdf` and `.txt`. But I've noticed that it doesn't return anything for all image extensions I've tried (`.bmp`, `.png`, `.jpg`, `.ico`).

```
uses
  ShLwApi, Windows, Dialogs;

const
    // ASSOCF enumerated values mapped to integer constants
    ASSOCF_INIT_NOREMAPCLSID = $00000001;
    ASSOCF_INIT_BYEXENAME = $00000002;
    ASSOCF_OPEN_BYEXENAME = $00000002;
    ASSOCF_INIT_DEFAULTTOSTAR = $00000004;
    ASSOCF_INIT_DEFAULTTOFOLDER = $00000008;
    ASSOCF_NOUSERSETTINGS = $00000010;
    ASSOCF_NOTRUNCATE = $00000020;
    ASSOCF_VERIFY = $00000040;
    ASSOCF_REMAPRUNDLL = $00000080;
    ASSOCF_NOFIXUPS = $00000100;
    ASSOCF_IGNOREBASECLASS = $00000200;
    
var
   Buffer: array [0..1024] of char;
   BufSize: DWord;
begin
   BufSize := Sizeof(Buffer);
   Buffer[0] := #0;
   AssocQueryString(
         ASSOCF_NOTRUNCATE,
         ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,
         '.bmp',
         'open',
         Buffer,
         @BufSize
   );
   ShowMessage(Buffer);
end;
```

**Further informations:**

It also works with image extensions, but only if asking for the executable associated to 'edit' instead of 'open'.

Double-clicking on a .bmp file causes the file is opened with the default Windows 10 photo viewer.

**Update**

Currently, my code is:

```
var
  Buffer: array [0..1024] of Char;
  BufSize: DWord;
  Res: HResult;
begin
  BufSize := Length(Buffer);
  Res := AssocQueryString(
    ASSOCF_REMAPRUNDLL or ASSOCF_NOTRUNCATE,
    (*ASSOCSTR_DELEGATEEXECUTE missing on Delphi 2007*) 18,
    '.bmp',
    nil,
    Buffer,
    @BufSize
  );
  If Res = S_OK then
    ShowMessage(Buffer)
  else
    ShowMessage('Error ' + IntToStr(Res) + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(Res));
```

It shows "{4ED3A719-CEA8-4BD9-910D-E252F997AFC2}". How to have the same result seen on Windows 7? (A dll or an executable filename)

Furthermore, I noticed that after changing `.bmp` into an non-existent (like '.abcde') return a similar result. For this I can't even know if there's an associated program.

Comment: What does [FindExecutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419.aspx) return for image files on your system?

Comment: @IInspectable: It results 31 (SE_ERR_NOASSOC -> "There is no association for the specified file type with an executable file." -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: If you leave the `pszExtra` parameter empty (pass `nil` instead of `'open'`), you'll see that the .bmp extension is actually associated with PhotoViewer.dll and not an executable (at least on Win7 64 - I'd suspect it's similar on Win10). `assoc .bmp` from a command prompt says it's a *Paint.Picture*, which according to `ftype Paint.Picture` is associated with `rundll32 PhotoViewer.dll`.

Comment: @KenWhite: I confirm that "assoc .bmp" says "Paint.Picture" also on Windows 10. I tried passing nil as pszExtra parameter but it's still resulting an empty string.

Comment: What do you want to do with that information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in comments, your machine's registrations for image file extensions are not using an application to open the files, they are using a DLL invoked by Rundll32 instead.

Per the [`ASSOCSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762475.aspx) documentation:

> ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE
>   An executable from a Shell verb command string. For example, this string is found as the (Default) value for a subkey such as `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ApplicationName\shell\Open\command`. **If the command uses Rundll.exe, set the ASSOCF_REMAPRUNDLL flag in the flags parameter of IQueryAssociations::GetString to retrieve the target executable**.
>
> Caution
>   **Not all app associations have executables. Do not assume that an executable will always be present**.

Per the [`ASSOCF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762471.aspx) documentation:

> ASSOCF_REMAPRUNDLL
>   Instructs `IQueryAssociations` methods to **ignore `Rundll.exe` and return information about its target**. Typically `IQueryAssociations` methods return information about the first `.exe` or `.dll` in a command string. If a command uses `Rundll.exe`, setting this flag tells the method to ignore `Rundll.exe` and return information about its target.

Also, when calling `AssocQueryString()`, try setting the `pszExtra` parameter to NULL instead of a specific verb.

Also, pay attention to the documentation for the last parameter of `AssocQueryString()`:

> cchOut [in, out]
>   Type: DWORD*
>
> A pointer to a value that, **when calling the function, is set to the number of characters in the pszOut buffer**. When the function returns successfully, the value is set to the number of characters actually placed in the buffer.

You are setting your `BufSize` variable to a **byte count** not a **character count**. Your code is assuming `Sizeof(Char)` is 1, but that is only true in Delphi 2007 and earlier. In Delphi 2009 and later, `Sizeof(Char)` is 2 instead.

And always check return values for errors.

Try this:

```
var
  Buffer: array [0..1024] of Char;
  BufSize: DWord;
  Res: HResult;
begin
  BufSize := Length(Buffer);
  Res := AssocQueryString(
    ASSOCF_REMAPRUNDLL or ASSOCF_NOTRUNCATE,
    ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,
    '.bmp',
    nil,
    Buffer,
    @BufSize
  );
  If Res = S_OK then
    ShowMessage(Buffer)
  else
    ShowMessage('Error ' + IntToStr(Res));
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
var
  Buffer: string;
  BufSize: DWord;
  Res: HResult;
begin
  BufSize := 0;
  Res := AssocQueryString(
    ASSOCF_REMAPRUNDLL or ASSOCF_NOTRUNCATE,
    ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,
    '.bmp',
    nil,
    nil,
    @BufSize
  );
  if Res = S_FALSE then
  begin
    SetLength(Buffer, BufSize-1);
    Res := AssocQueryString(
      ASSOCF_REMAPRUNDLL or ASSOCF_NOTRUNCATE,
      ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,
      '.bmp',
      nil,
      PChar(Buffer),
      @BufSize
    );
  end;
  If Res = S_OK then
    ShowMessage(Buffer)
  else
    ShowMessage('Error ' + IntToStr(Res));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks alot for suggestions and documentation quotes.
I've tried your solutions but in both cases AssocQueryString returns -2147023741 on my system.

Comment: You're right. Maybe I've misunderstood something but both your code examples set the ASSOCF_REMAPRUNDLL flag. If I double click on a '.bmp' file, then it's opened with the Windows 10 photo viewer. Why AssocQueryString is still returning ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION?

Comment: @ExDev: The code works fine on Win7, it returns `PhotoViewer.dll` as expected. When I run the exact same code on Win10, it fails. I notice that `.bmp` on Win10 has no `open` verb (only `edit` and `printto`). Like the docs say, an association is not guaranteed to have an executable. However, `ASSOCSTR_DELEGATEEXECUTE` works for `.bmp` on Win10 (though its verbs do not have an explicit `DelegateExecute` value), and the returned CLSID belongs to an "Association Launch Execute Command" COM object, so the difference in behaviors likely has to do with use of `IExecuteCommand` vs command-ilne.

Comment: I've updated my question by adding my current code. It's returning "{4ED3A719-CEA8-4BD9-910D-E252F997AFC2}". Is there something wrong in code?
I mean, could I obtain the same result seen on Win7? ('PhotoViewer.dll')

Comment: @ExDev I still want to know: what do you want to do with the association information?

Comment: @andlabs: Mainly, I want to check if a file's extension has an associated "viewer application" before downloading the file in a temporary folder and opening it. But I also would be interested in mere showing of the associated executable/library filename.

Comment: @ExDev if that is all you want, you can use `ASSOCSTR_FRIENDLYAPPNAME`.

Comment: It works for that purpouse but the reason why I've posted the question is that OS gets the "PhotoViewer.dll" (in some way) but I can't do the same on Windows 10, I find it a little annoying...